# How to make PC ask for which hard-drive to boot from, every time you turn on PC?

Tags: boot

I have partitioned Linux in one hard-drive, and windows in one. I want it so every time I turn my PC on, it asks for which hard-drive I would like to boot from instead of having to press the F short key to boot

Thanks

Comment: Install grub on both disks, and choose from the grub menu which OS to boot into (in fact, installing grub only on the Linux disk, and making that disk the first in the bios boot sequence would also work with the BIOSes I have experience with).